# Flutter - StreamBuilder seems to not be listening to the stream after changing page and coming back

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page where I use Bloc to get the text from the search bar above to filter the list below based on the text inputed.

The Bloc and the stream are both working as expected when I first enter the page, however, when I pop it and come back to the page, I can see that the data is being added to the bloc via sink add, but the streambuilder doesn't rebuild itself, it looks like it isn't listening to the stream anymore, idk.

This is where I have the page with trouble (Characteristics) being called

```
List<Widget> _steps = [
    CharacteristicsProvider(child: Characteristics()),
    Optionals(),
    Prices(),
    Advertiser(),
    Photos(),
  ];

  Widget build(context) {
    var mediaQD = MediaQuery.of(context);
    _safeAreaSize = mediaQD.size;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _willPopCallback,
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffEFEFEE),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Criar Anúncio"),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                _getStepProgress(),
                _steps[_curPage - 1],
              ],
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
```

This is the page where the StreamBuilder doesn't rebuild itself after the sink.add is called:

```
class _SelectionPageState extends State<SelectionPage> {
  SearchBarBloc bloc;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    bloc = SearchBarProvider.of(context);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    bloc.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    List<String> sortedList = widget.list;
    if (!widget.isOrdered) {
      sortedList.sort();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffECECEC),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: widget.title,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SearchBar(
            onTextChange: (s) {
              bloc.changeText(s);
            },
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: buildList(bloc: bloc, sortedList: sortedList),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList({SearchBarBloc bloc, List<String> sortedList}) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.text,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print("data1");
          List filteredList =
              filterList(text: snapshot.data, sortedList: sortedList);
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: filteredList.length,
            itemExtent: 55,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black38)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(filteredList[index]),
                  onTap: () {
                    bloc.clearText();
                    widget.onTap(widget.list.firstWhere(
                        (element) => element.contains(filteredList[index])));
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }

  /// Filters the list based on search bar's text.
  List filterList({String text, List<String> sortedList}) {
    if (text == null || text == "") {
      return sortedList;
    }
    var filteredList = sortedList
        .where((element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
    return filteredList;
  }
}
```

Finally, this is my Bloc page:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class SearchBarBloc {
  final _text = PublishSubject<String>();

  // listen to stream
  Observable<String> get text => _text.stream;

  // Changing data
  Function(String) get changeText => _text.sink.add;

  clearText() {
    changeText("");
  }

  dispose() {
    _text.close();
    _text.sink.close();
  }
}
```

I would expect it to continue filtering the list, like it's already doing the first time I enter the page. But whenever I go to other page and reenter the Characteristics page, it doesn't go through the StreamBuilder anymore after changing text, and because of that, the list doesn't get filtered anymore.

Comment: Ohhh, sorry, I found the problem...
I forgot to add the SearchBarProvider before opening the page... Now that I've added it, it is working as expected!

Comment: If you found an answer you can add that as an answer. Don't put answers or "Solved" in your question/title

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue... I forgot to add the SearchBarProvider for the page before opening it. After I added it, the page started working as expected.